# Can not connect to Windows HomeGroup and Internet at the same time

Tags: networking, internet, samba, workgroup

I Ubuntu 14.04 and made all the changes on Samba to allow me to connect to my Windows Homegroup. Trouble is I can now either connect to the homegroup or the internet, but not both at the same time. I'm using Windows 7 on the other 2 PCs.

If I'm on the internet, and try connecting to the network it says "Unable to access connection. Failed to retrieve share list from server: No such file or directory."

If I'm off the internet, I can access the homegroup but then if I try to connect to the internet, I lose the connection to the homegroup. Is this normal?

Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 0):

This sounds to me, from the information that you provided, as if your internet connection is in some way changing the IP address of the network interface that you use to access your homegroup.

This would happen if you are using any form of a dial-up technology, or if your router device is not in fact on the same IP range as the Windows 7 machines.

Without more information regarding your network setup, this is roughly as far as I can speculate for now...